# Githubbing a ClickOnce application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, github, clickonce

I want to upload my application to github so people could start aiding in it's development.

What issues should I be aware of? I know theres a matter or security...they would not be able to open the solution without the .pfx file right? But I've read that if people get access to your certificate that they could sign malware with your certificate.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [delay signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t07a3dye(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i wont be using an actual paid certificate...I would be using the "Test certificate"